# How shoud I sort a phrase using compareTo in Java

Tags: java, sorting, compareto, stringtokenizer

Hello I need to make a program that splits a phrase and afther that it sort it in alphabetical order. My teacher suggest that we shoud use StringTokenizer for the split and comapreTo for the sort.

So far I have splited it and now I am struggling with the sorting part.

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer("Afara este soare si frumos");
        while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
            System.out.println(st.nextToken());
        }
```

It results:  "1Afara   2este 3soare  4si  5frumos"

and afther the sorting part shoud be: "1Afara 2este 3frumos 4si 5soara"

Any advice woud be good! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Put the words into an array or a `List`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
  String mystring = "Afara este soare si frumos";
  String[] sortedArray = mystring.split("\\s");
  Arrays.sort(sortedArray);
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sortedArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to store the strings in an `List`, and use the [`Collections.sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) method in the Java standard Library.

Answer (score 0):

The compareTo is a method in the String class, it can be used to compare one string with another lexicographically and it returns an int which can be determined the ordering mechanism See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html.

If your teacher is fine with you using an internal API, then as mentioned in other answers, you may use java.util.Arrays#sort to sort the array (if you have an array) or you can use java.util.Collections

If not, then you can use any sorting algorithm with compareTo to sort your array.